# Math typestting improper after copy and paste. Can I get Mathematica to "refresh" the entire expression?

Tags: formatting, display

I copied the content shown in the square brackets from that shown selected in the rounded brackets.  When I pasted the content, the "hats" were misplaced, as shown in all but the first two terms of the pasted text.

The first two terms were fixed by simply copying the '^' and pasting it over itself.  That causes the character to move back to its proper location.

Is there a way to get that to happen without touching each misplaced character?

This is the content being copied:

[image: Selected for copy]

This is the content after pasting:

[image]

---

Here is an example from a smaller expression with the same problem:

[image: Misplaced hats]

And the cell expression:

```
Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["a", 
     RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "1"}]], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"]}], "+", 
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["a", 
     RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "2"}]], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicJ]", "^"]}], "+", 
   RowBox[{
    SubscriptBox["a", 
     RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "3"}]], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
    OverscriptBox["\[GothicK]", "^"]}]}], TraditionalForm]],
 FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]], "Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.72528311041591*^9, 3.725283111409934*^9}}]
```

The same cell with some of the hats fixed:

[image: Some hats fixed]

And the corresponding cell expression:

```
 Cell[TextData[Cell[BoxData[
  FormBox[
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{
     SubscriptBox["a", 
      RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "1"}]], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"]}], "+", 
    RowBox[{
     SubscriptBox["a", 
      RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "2"}]], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicJ]", "^"]}], "+", 
    RowBox[{
     SubscriptBox["a", 
      RowBox[{"1", "\[InvisibleComma]", "3"}]], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^"], 
     OverscriptBox["\[GothicK]", "^"]}]}], TraditionalForm]],
  FormatType->"TraditionalForm"]], "Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.72528311041591*^9, 3.725283111409934*^9}, {3.725292068048725*^9, 3.725292090693556*^9}}]
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to include the `Cell` expression of the cell that is being copied, which can be obtained by using the menu item `Cell | Show Expression`.

Comment: It looks like the `DiacriticalPositioning` is getting screwed up when you paste. In addition to Carls solution you could try explicitly adding it to your expression, e.g. `OverscriptBox["\[GothicI]", "^",DiacriticalPositioning->True]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like an issue worth reporting to support. Here are a few workarounds:

1. Evaluate the following expression after the problematic cell:

`NotebookWrite[PreviousCell[], NotebookRead@PreviousCell[]]`

Animation:

[image]

2. Use the following button to fix a cell containing the insertion point:

`Button[
    "Reset formatting",
    With[{p=ParentCell @@ SelectedCells[EvaluationNotebook[]]},
        NotebookWrite[p, NotebookRead[p]]
    ]
]`

Animation:

[image]

3. Use `Cell | Show Expression` and edit the contents by deleting and restoring a character.

Animation:

[image]